# Get 2 record of a particular category based on foreignkey value in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table `product` and `mastercategory`

product has columns

```
id - pk, 
title- varchar,
price - varchar,
selling_price - varchar, 
description - varchar, 
is_approved - bool,
is_live - bool,
is_visible - bool,
category_id - fk (foreign_key of category table)
```

mastercategory has columns

```
id - pk, 
name - varchar, 
is_active - bool,
is_hotcategory - bool,
```

I want to get 2 latest record of each category where `is_hotcategory` is `true`

How can I get this

I tried it with this:

```
select cp.id,cp.title, cp.category_id from product cp 
left join mastercategory cmc on cp.category_id = cmc.id where cmc.is_hotcategory = 1 and cp.id in (
select max(cp.id) As id
from product cp 
where cp.is_visible = 1 and cp.is_live= 1 and cp.is_approved=1 
group by category_id 

union all

select max(cp.id) As id
from product cp 
left join mastercategory cmc on cp.category_id = cmc.id 
where cmc.is_hotcategory = 1 and 
cp.is_visible = 1 and cp.is_live= 1 and cp.is_approved=1 and
(cp.id not in (select max(cp.id) 
from product cp 
where cp.is_visible = 1 and cp.is_live= 1 and cp.is_approved=1 group by category_id )) group by category_id 
) order by category_id asc;
```

I'm getting last record of each category then getting 2nd last record of each category then with union combining both the search query

I think it will work but what if I have to get more than 2 record of each category.
Is there any other solution to that.

Comment: `MySQL` <> `SQL Server` Please tag only the database that you are using

Comment: ok actually i thought the logic will be same on both .

Comment: It may or may not, but unless you are specifically looking for a solution in both products, please don't tag them as each runs its own variant of SQL. In fact tagging SQL (which I have done) is also highly important.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER in CTE and rn<3 in outer query.

Comment: ok. No problm i have change it. @DaleK

Comment: @Akina can you please send me the query. i'm not that good with database queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    select cp.id, cp.title, cp.category_id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cp.category_id ORDER BY cp.id DESC) rn
    from product cp 
    join mastercategory cmc on cp.category_id = cmc.id 
    where cmc.is_hotcategory
      and cp.is_visible
      and cp.is_live
      and cp.is_approved 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn < 3;
```

I assume that "latest record of each category" is the product row with greatest `id` from the rows with the same `category_id` (I have not found a column similar to `created_at`). If not then adjust frame specification accordingly.

Comment: thanx u are awsm this is want i want . and it working fine. But can you explain it in brief.

Comment: @sandeepnegi `ROW_NUMBER()` (read its description and about window functions at all in Reference Manual) divides all rows to groups (according to PARTITION BY expression) then sorts them (according to ORDER BY expression) and enumerates. Using above expressions the most late row in each catregory have this value = 1, the next row have the value = 2. And outer query simply selects these 2 rows for each category (or only one if the category have no second row). For to understand - comment WHERE in outer query, sort by (`cp.category_id, cp.id DESC`) and investigate the output.